# Why i get 404 on querying select2 in django admin?

Tags: django, admin, jquery-select2

I added select2 to urls.py:

```
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
```

And make widget in admin:

```
class WordSelect2MultipleWidgetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SeoTextCategory
        fields = (
            'words',
        )
        widgets = {
            'words': ModelSelect2MultipleWidget(
                model=Word_Replace,
                search_fields=['word__icontains']),
        }

class SeoTextCategoryAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = WordSelect2MultipleWidgetForm
```

In my admin it looks great, but i get 404 when trying type something:

```
[14/Nov/2016 11:21:47] "GET /select2/fields/auto.json?term=%D0%BF%D1%80&field_id=MTQwNDI5MDk2NTQ5OTYw%3A1c6BaH%3AaaeoV6gvQ0QtjH5FC1q3VDwwFcY HTTP/1.1" 404 932
```

Am i need to do something in views.py?

Answer (score 1):

most likely not installed cache backend. try to install `memcached` or `redis`.